# Concatenate dataframes while making sure boolean value is not converted into integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have df1 and df2 that I want to combine into one dataframe in a for loop. The 2 dataframes are identical
df1 looks like this

```
id booleanValue
0     True
1     False
```

df2 looks like this

```
id booleanValue
2     True
3     np.nan
```

I did

```
total_df = pd.Dataframe()
total_df = pd.concat([total_df, df1], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

I was hoping to get

```
id booleanValue
0     True
1     False
2     True
3     NaN
```

but I got

```
id booleanValue
0     0.0
1     1.0
2     0.0
3     0.0
```

Is there a way to concatenate so that boolean value doesn't get converted into integer and np.nan will remain as np.nan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution working nice, only is necessary upgrade pandas, because [Nullable Boolean Data Type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/boolean.html) working from `pandas 1.0.0+`:

```
df1['booleanValue'] = df1['booleanValue'].astype('boolean')
df2['booleanValue'] = df2['booleanValue'].astype('boolean')

total_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
print (total_df.dtypes)
id                int64
booleanValue    boolean
dtype: object

print (total_df)
   id  booleanValue
0   0          True
1   1         False
2   2          True
3   3          <NA>
```

---

Solution if not convert to `boolean` - get `object` dtype:

```
total_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
print (total_df)
   id booleanValue
0   0         True
1   1        False
2   2         True
3   3          NaN

print (total_df.dtypes)
id               int64
booleanValue    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: upgrading pandas is too risky for my use case since I manage a lot of models for my company, I have decided to fix the possible values to False and True instead of False,True and None. thanks for the info! I didn't know before this null boolean value is working for the new pandas version.